# ERROR instalacion de proyecto angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

he instalado la ultima versión de node js la 12 + angular cdi pero al crear un nuevo proyecto con ng new NombreDelproyecto me devuelve el siguiente error.

```html
npm WARN deprecated mixin-deep@1.3.1: Critical bug fixed in v2.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@2.0.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
```

Aun así veo que el proyecto se ha generado pero supongo que hay muchos packetes que por culpa del error no ha instalado ya que al hacer un `ng serve` no funciona me sale el siguiente error

```html
$ ng serve
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\carsClient".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\carsClient".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Grupo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:151:11)
    at WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost.resolveBuilder (C:\Users\Grupo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js:31:40)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\Grupo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:135:55)
    at async ServeCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\Grupo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:127:9)
    at async Object.runCommand (C:\Users\Grupo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:178:24)
    at async default_1 (C:\Users\Grupo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:32:31)
```

Si alguien sabe como arreglarlo seria de gran ayuda. Gracias

Comment: Lo de arriba son warnings, no están relacionados con el error posterior. ¿Has creado el proyecto directamente dentro de xampp?

Comment: Si, Lo he creado dentro de xammp directamente, ahora he creado uno fuera y ha funcionado perfectamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaba intentando arrancar el ng serve desde la carpeta de directorio de xammp. al sacarlo en otro directorio ya funciona perfecto. Gracias